# unable to get Json data for the second time when requesting with URL

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, url

I have a function which get and process a `JsonData`. My code is like this:

```
def getData(link,row):
    u=urllib2.urlopen(link).read();
    jsonObject=json.loads(u);
    # do some stuff
    return (jsonObject[u'pagination']['next_url'],row);

json,newRow=getData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/****/media/recent?access_token=*****",0);
while (len(json )!= 0):
    json,newRow=getData(json,newRow);
```

when I call the `getData` function for the first time, it gives me the correct respond! But when I call it for the second time in `while`, I got the error like this:

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'loads'

It is interesting that the `u` value in second call is logic. it is something like:

```
{"pagination":{"next_max_tag_id":"1139055135096994516","deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id ............ }
```

Why do I get this error in later function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite the `json` definition. It started as an imported module, then got redefined as a unicode string.

Try renaming your variable:

```
j,newRow=getData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/****/media/recent?access_token=*****",0);
while j:
    j,newRow=getData(j,newRow);
```